# Node.js: Choose right architecture for HTTP-proxy to download many files to each user and return result as archive

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, architecture, zlib

It's more architectural question. I need someone point me in which way to build the process to achieve best performance. I'm newcomer in Node so you need to chew the answer for me :)

**I want:** Node.js HTTP-proxy. That proxy download files for my users.

**Input Data:**

1. We have 10 users simultaneously
2. Each user asks us to download 100 files (in single request)
3. Each file is about 20Mb and comes to us in chunks.

**I want:**

1. Download files and send them to user
2. And I want to stick them together with Zlib *(means actually I don't want compress them, I just want user to get the single download-result instead of 100 files in his download folder)*
3. And I want NOT to cache the result on the server side *(means I want to stick gzip result on the fly and send to user. Otherwise I will get memory troubles on the server)*.

**Architectural question:** ***how to build the process?*** Or if to be precise:

1. *Do the whole stuff in the single event loop, each task in separate worker or something in-between?*
2. *Should I move gziping task to the separate worker? If yes, separate worker for each user or just a common gziping worker?*
3. *What should I gzip and send to the user: file chunk, file or the set of files?*
4. *What about simulataneous downloading/gziping? Means what I should and shouldn't do simultaneously?*

**P.S.** pretty much questions, but they all about the single task I need to solve. You can answer all them or just specific one - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How exactly user asking for files? HTTP GET request made by browser? Or custom client side app?

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy server knows which files user need to download. So user just said "Hey server, download all that stuff for me at once". There is no sense for user to ask for each file separately.

Comment: Please, read my question again and answer it. How exactly user asking for files? Custom app or browser? It is really important here.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy HTTP GET is made by browser. That's enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. If Browser requests for files, in this case you can't just write 100 files into folder, since you don't control user's machine. Only thing you can do, is to return one single file to the user in order to response of user request. In this case only thing you can do is to concat files on server side. But obliviously you also can't download 2Gb of data in instant time, so appropriate algorithm here can be:
1. User request for files
2. Server start to download them one by one or parallel in groups and receives data from external resources. Server uses read streams for that (http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).
3. Server opens write stream for response. 
4. For each received chunk of data server marks it for which file it belongs, pack it, and sends it to user into writeable stream.

NOTE: resulting file will be a mess of mixed chunks of 100 different files. Client will need something to unpack it. Obliviously you can try to use some packer like gz, zip or tar server side to send some file which makes sense to user (pack different chunks of files by some existing algo and send as stream to user).

In general I would suggest that 2Gb will be very hard to send as single file any way. In this case can write client app to do this. There https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit module that can help you write client apps.

NOTE 2:
Also it is very important to design cluster and request processing to work with domains to avoid whole app crashing. Because it is very hard (sometimes impossible) in node.js to catch an error raised (In my experiance this happening very often) inside a stream. Read http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html for more info.

Comment: desktop app is an yesterday, it's easier to me to miss some functionality. Yeah, but can you tell what to do in which thread? *The main problem I'm newcomer Node and need someone specify how to organize the whole process

Comment: Node.js works in a bit different way. You don't put separate processes in different threads (like downloading thread, compressing thread). All you do is launching node.js itself in several threads. Look at documentation here to understand how it works http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html. Also it is very important to design cluster and request processing to work with domains (it is not related to DNS) http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html to avoid whole app crashing, which can become pretty common on transferring such amounts of data.

Comment: thanks. Can you include more details about `make it work with domains` into your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ou, I just mentioned it, because it is very hard (sometimes impossible) in node.js to catch an error raised (In my experiance this happening very often) inside a stream. And when it will popup, the whole application gonna crash. In this case I for you stream based app usage of domain a kind of mandatory. All other info here http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html